# A complex alert system Redux-observable. not dispatch action at the end of an epic

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am trying to do a "complexe alert system" in redux + redux-observable.

The requirement are:

- an action should request an alert: REQUEST_ALERT
- an action should create alert + add an id: SET_ALERT (done in epic)
- an alert should be close after 3 s: DISMISS_ALERT (done in epic)
- an alert can be close by a user click: DISMISS_ALERT

(We could refactor to use directly SET_ALERT Without REQUEST_ALERT directly inside the reducer but this is not the problem here)

I almost achieve my goal with:

```
// generate the alert from the request
// you can ignore it if refactor with only REQUEST_ALERT
export const generateAlert$ = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_ALERT)
    .map(action => ({
        type: SET_ALERT,
        payload: generateAlertPayload(), 
        // just create action de type SET_ALERT and add an id 
      })
    )
  }
// the real important part
export const timeoutDismissAlert$ = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(SET_ALERT)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Rx.Observable.empty()
      .concat(
        // I wait for max delay and send the payload dismiss_alert
        Rx.Observable.of(action)
          .delay(maxDelay)
          .map(({payload}) => ({type: DISMISS_ALERT, payload: payload.id}))
          // I make a race with the user click vs the delay 
          .race(
            action$.ofType(DISMISS_ALERT)
              .skipWhile(({payload}) => payload !== action.payload.id)
              .first()
              .map(() => null)
          )
      )
      // I would like to dispatch an action only if the delay win
      .map((a) => a ? a : {type: "I_DONT_WANT"})
    )
  }
```

does there is a way to not dispatch an action at the end of an epic ? or better Rxjs way to achieve it ?

Comment: Awesome, good luck. Did you have a specific question or are you just letting us know what your project is? If the latter, this is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you just want to "cancel" your delayed observable whenever a user clicks, and `takeUntil` could help with that.

I imagine the desired epic to look something like this:

```
// action creator
const dismissAlert = payload => ({ type: DISMISS_ALERT, payload });

// epic
const dismissAlert$ = action$ => {
    return action$.ofType(SET_ALERT)
        .mergeMap(action => {
            const dismiss$ = action$.ofType(DISMISS_ALERT)
                .filter(({ payload }) => payload === action.payload.id);

            // the interesting part
            return Rx.Observable.timer(maxDelay)
                .mapTo(dismissAlert(action.payload.id))
                .takeUntil(dismiss$);
        });
};
```

Now the nested observable produces either a single DISMISS_ALERT action or nothing if user clicks before `maxDelay` interval elapses.